# why tableview didn't scroll if i use constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

1. I am used constraints for my tableview.
2. If data exists the view of the phone screen then its didn't scroll.
3. My Project need auto layout. so i can't disable it,many of them suggestion to disable auto layout in the file inspector.

   Tableview row height is 70.
4. I have spent more than 2 hours but cant get the right answer.

Comment: Autolayout has nothing to do with tableView scrolling, how can be so sure that autolayout is creating problem?

Comment: i just seen one answer in stackover flow @iphonic,in that they suggest to remove autolayout

Comment: I hope you are not using any third party that might be causing the problem?

Comment: @iphonic i didn't use any third party.....\

Comment: Usually the table doesn't scroll because A/ It's bigger that you expect it to be so it doesn't really need to scroll B/ the content doesn't set its size correctly so it's smaller than you expect it to be and the table doesn't need to scroll. Printing `table.frame` and `table.contentSize` to the console will tell you both sizes and you can see what case is your problem. Then you have to inspect your constraints and find out which constraints are missing or are not set properly. Warnings in Interface Builder are usually very helpful.